# ComboBox numeric MatchEntry

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have a `ComboBox` in my userform and it has list of numeric values. Different Combobox autocompletes when I press alphabet characters but it does not work with numeric characters.

Is it possible to set `MatchEntry` (or any other property) to autocomplete when I click numeric value?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For i = 100 To 1000 '<~~ Adding sample data for testing
        ComboBox1.AddItem "Sid" & i
        ComboBox1.AddItem i
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    For i = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ComboBox1.Value = Left(ComboBox1.List(i), Len(ComboBox1.Value)) Then
            ComboBox1.Value = ComboBox1.List(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention it is Style DropDownList.

Comment: ...and of course forgot to give you feedback. If ComboBox would be DropDownCombo style it probably would work. But here it is not working.